# Shipping aws-cli with macos app

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, aws-cli

I am working on a MacOS app that provides a GUI interface on top of `aws s3 sync` command.

The app does not make any assumptions on whether `aws` command is present and tries to install both `brew` and `aws` command via brew in the setup.

I am using `Process` class from swift 3 and relying on `which` command to detect `brew` and `aws` command and if that is not available, try to install it. Roughly, the script interfaced by swift 3 looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

if ! [ -x "$(command -v $1)" ]; then
    echo $2
    if [ $1 == "brew" ]; then
        /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" &>/dev/null
    fi
    if [ $1 == "aws" ]; then
        brew install awscli &>/dev/null
    fi
fi
```

But on different MacOS versions, I am running into issues with managing the automatic installation.

I was wondering if it is possible to ship a specific version of the "awscli" with the app. I am looking at something like

`cp /usr/local/bin/aws <project folder>` and then removing all the auto install scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the bundled installer.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-bundle.html

Answer (score 1):

The AWS command-line tools are meant to be used directly to perform administrative tasks. They are not intended to be embedded into an application, nor should your application attempt to install them automatically.

Similarly, Homebrew is intended for developers to use to install and manage third-party software. It should **never** be installed automatically, as it may have some global effects on system behavior.

Your application should interact with the S3 API directly, or by using a library. (Amazon does not have an AWS SDK for Cocoa, but there are a number of third-party options available.)

Comment: I like the answer but I have a few limitations. I want to use `aws s3 sync` command and the best aws sdk's that I know of is boto but it does not have the sync command. The closest thing I could think of is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto_rsync (I can use this assuming mac comes bundles with pre installed python).

Similarly, closest OSX aws sdk is https://github.com/nickoneill/aws-sdk-osx
Not sure about it's stability though. 

That's why I made a call to use aws-cli bundled with app directly.